# Google App Engine Remote API does not work from local client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, remoteapi

This is using the Python SDK version 1.8.0.

My remote API works fine using `remote_api_shell.py`, but doesn't work when trying to accessing from within a python script.  I'm using the [sample code from google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi#Using_Remote_API_in_a_Local_Client):

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
import getpass

def auth_func():
  return (raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:'))

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,
                               'localhost:8080')
```

and I'm also importing the `fix_sys_path()` from `dev_appserver.py` to set my `sys.path` correctly for the google app engine SDK:

```
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

that adds, among other paths, the following line to my `sys.path`:

```
'/google_appengine_1.8.0/lib/fancy_urllib'
```

However, the following error is thrown when the above call to `remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi()` is called:

```
opener.add_handler(fancy_urllib.FancyProxyHandler())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FancyProxyHandler'
```

Comment: It seems the google-provided `fix_sys_path()` does not correctly locate the `fancy_urllib` module. `fix_sys_path()` sets the path to:  

    `/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/`

However, the module is actually located here:

    `/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/`

So I just copied the contents of the deepest `fancy_urllib` into the parent directory.  

This is a workaround and I don't like modifying the SDK like this. Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: File a bug on the google issue tracker.  https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: Yes, this definitely seems like a bug and that those files belong one directory up in the hierarchy. Report the issue on the tracker.

Comment: Tried reproducing the problem and it seems to have disappeared with the current SDK (1.9.18) -- i.e, your sample code works fine now.  Can you please check this and close the question...?

Answer (score 2):

Wait 7 years, and it all seems to work fine.